# How to extract keywords from HTML page in C#?

Tags: c#, html-parsing

Basically I want to extract keywords or words or tokens that are present in the webpage after removing the stopwords. Does anybody know how to do this? Code in C# would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should tag this with [c#]

Comment: if all you want is to get data from web page you can use JQuery like the following $('#testDIV').load('JQueryPage.aspx');

Answer (score 0):

Use an HTML parsing library like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Once you load an HTML document with it, you can query it with Xpath syntax - it exposes the HTML in a similar way to an `XmlDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) that [Oded](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) mentions will help you get at the plain text inside the HTML, but to extract keywords from the webpage after removing the stopwords you'll need to do more work. There's a good informative answer from [Joseph Turian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82733/joseph-turian) to this question: [How do I extract keywords used in text?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1575345/575530)