# Tool/API to extract keyword(s) in a sentence in .net

Tags: .net, search, text, dictionary, keyword

I am looking for a tool/api in .net, which can roughly extract the key words in a sentence. For example, if i have a article with title  "PIX: World's thinnest 15-inch laptop, Dell XPS 15z", i want to extract keyword(s), e.g. DELL, XPS 15z, laptop etc. so that i can search those keywords in other articles and present the user with similar articles.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here:

- [Keyword Extraction in C# with Word Co-occurrence Algorithm](http://www.tsjensen.com/blog/2010/03/14/Keyword+Extraction+In+C+With+Word+Cooccurrence+Algorithm.aspx)
- [Atrax Keyword Extraction Algorithm](http://www.tsjensen.com/blog/2008/09/07/Atrax+Keyword+Extraction+Algorithm.aspx)
- [How do I extract keywords used in text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575246/how-do-i-extract-keywords-used-in-text)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do search of text and present related articles, you might well be interested in [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/).  It will index a body of text and accept standard search engine-style queries.  It will even do Google-style presentation of search results, such as highlighting the search terms found in the document.

It is more work than using the algorithms Tarkus mentioned, but it will solve more of your problems and save you from having to write your own search engine (which is a non-trivial task).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use grouping in regular expressions to extract the words around Dell.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for this kind of tool also, and I found this page http://termcoord.wordpress.com/about/testing-of-term-extraction-tools/free-term-extractors/

You can choose from any of the tools. This helps me a lot of options.